# Python: Expanding the scope of the iterator variable in the any() function

Tags: python, scope, any

I wrote some structurally equivalent real world code, where I anticipated the result for `firstAdjective` would be `quick`. But the result shows that `word` is out of scope. What is a neat solution that will overcome this but still retain the 'linguistic' style of what I want to do?

```
>>> text = 'the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'
>>> adjectives = ['slow', 'quick', 'brown', 'lazy']
>>> if any(word in text for word in adjectives):
...     firstAdjective = word
...     
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 2, in <module>
NameError: name 'word' is not defined
```

Comment: This does not work, as the 'word' object only exists during the evaluation of the condition. Once it is done finding whether the condition is true or false,  the word object does not exist anymore.

Comment: What's the expected output if `text= 'a b'` and `adjectives= ['b','a']`?

Comment: If we were to use `adjectives = ['slow', 'brown', 'lazy', 'quick']` as the list of adjectives, should it returns 'quick' (first in the text) or 'brown' (firs in the adjective list). (this is the same as Rawing's comment).  
The example you are giving leads us to confusion as 'quick' is the first adjective in both the list of adj and the text ....

Comment: `firstAdjective = next(word in text for word in adjectives, None)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `next` on a *generator expression*:

```
firstAdjective = next((word for word in adjectives if word in text), None)

if firstAdjective:
    ...
```

A default value of `None` is returned when the word is not found (credit @Bakuriu)

**Trial**:

```
>>> firstadjective = next((word for word in adjectives if word in text), None)
>>> firstadjective
'quick'
```

Comment: `next` can provide a default value too: `firstAdjective = next((word for ...), None): if firstAdjective is None: ...`

Comment: Sprite! I didn't remember that. Thanks

Comment: Now, change the list of adjectives by `adjectives = ['slow', 'brown', 'lazy', 'quick']`. You'll get the first adjective in the list, instead of first adjective in the text (and with the changed adjectives list, you'll get 'brown', and not 'quick'). See Mutational Meltdown's answer for looking at their place in the text instead of the list of adjectives.

Comment: @HolyDanna That's not how `any` works. From OP's code, `any` will *return* on the first word in the list and not the way you suggest. If you changed the order of the list, `any` *returns* on `brown` not `quick`

Comment: I used the solution of @Moses but with this variation.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like

```
for word in filter(lambda x: x in adjectives, text.split()):
    print word
```

work?

Comment: I think David only wants the first adjective, where your solution would show all three of them.

Comment: A `break` would do in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Your example does not work because the `word` variable only exists during the evaluation of the condition. Once it is done finding whether the condition is true or false, the variable goes out of scope and does not exist anymore.

Even declaring it first doesn't help, as it doesn't affect the existing variable:

```
text = 'the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'
adjectives = ['slow', 'quick', 'brown', 'lazy']
word = None
if any(word in text for word in adjectives):
    print(word)
```

> None

Therefore, you have to do it differently, using the `next` function:

```
text = 'the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'
adjectives = ['slow', 'quick', 'brown', 'lazy']
word = next((word for word in adjectives if word in text), None)
if word:
    print(word)
```

> quick

Note, perhaps `word` is a misleading variable name here, because it doesn't necessarily have to match a whole word. i.e.

```
text = 'the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'
adjectives = ['slo', 'uick', 'rown', 'azy']
word = next((word for word in adjectives if word in text), None)
if word:
    print(word)
```

> uick

so it might be best to split the text into words first:

```
text = 'the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'
adjectives = ['slow', 'quick', 'brown', 'lazy']
word_list = text.split()
word = next((word for word in adjectives if word in word_list), None)
if word:
    print(word)
```

but note that if we change the adjectives order:

```
text = 'the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'
adjectives = ['brown', 'quick', 'slow', 'lazy']
word_list = text.split()
word = next((word for word in adjectives if word in word_list), None)
if word:
    print(word)
```

we get:

> brown

which isn't the first adjective in the text.

Therefore, we need to check in the order of the words in the text, not the order of adjectives in the list.

```
text = 'the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'
adjectives = ['brown', 'quick', 'slow', 'lazy']
word_list = text.split() # NOTE: this "optimization" is no longer necessary now
word = next((word for word in word_list if word in adjectives), None)
if word:
    print(word)
```

[credit to HolyDanna for spotting this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38476877/python-expanding-the-scope-of-the-iterator-variable-in-the-any-function/38477305?noredirect=1#comment64357249_38477305)

Comment: You look at their place in the list of adjectives, and not in the text. You should go for 'word for word in text.split() it word in adjectives', if you want to look at their place in the text.

Comment: In Python 2.7 at least, it appears that text.split() is actually necessary. See my edited (and downgraded) Answer below. I entered it as another Answer because I do not know how to insert code into comments like this one.

Answer (score -1):

```
>>> text = 'the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'
>>>
>>> # 1. Case with no match among the adjectives: Result None as expected
>>> adjectives = ['slow', 'crippled']
>>> firstAdjective = next((word for word in adjectives if word in text), None)
>>> firstAdjective
>>>   
>>> # 2. Case with a match to 1st available in adjectives but actually 2nd in the text
>>> adjectives = ['slow', 'brown', 'quick', 'lazy']
>>> firstAdjective = next((word for word in adjectives if word in text), None)
>>> firstAdjective
'brown'
>>> # 3. Case with a match to 1st available in the text, which is what is wanted
>>> firstAdjective = next((word for word in text.split() if word in adjectives), None)
>>> firstAdjective
'quick'
>>> # 4. Case where .split() is omitted. NOTE: This does not work. 
>>> # In python 2.7 at least, .split() is required
>>> firstAdjective = next((word for word in text if word in adjectives), None)
>>> firstAdjective
>>>
```