# 'in' operator: text containing words versus list of words

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, split

Why does example 3 below, which uses `text.split()`, produce the correct result, while example 4 is incorrect - i.e. it produces no result, just like example 1.

And why does example 2 still produce a result (even though it not the desired result), despite the fact that it does NOT use `text.split()`?

```
>>> text = 'the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'
```

1. Case with no match among the adjectives: Result None as expected

   ```
   >>> adjectives = ['slow', 'crippled']
   >>> firstAdjective = next((word for word in adjectives if word in text), None)
   >>> firstAdjective
   >>>
   ```
2. Case with a match to 1st available in adjectives but actually 2nd in the text:

   ```
   >>> adjectives = ['slow', 'brown', 'quick', 'lazy']
   >>> firstAdjective = next((word for word in adjectives if word in text), None)
   >>> firstAdjective
   'brown'
   ```
3. Case with a match to 1st available in the text, which is what is wanted

   ```
   >>> firstAdjective = next((word for word in text.split() if word in adjectives), None)
   >>> firstAdjective
   'quick'
   ```
4. Case where `.split()` is omitted. NOTE: This does not work.

   ```
   >>> firstAdjective = next((word for word in text if word in adjectives), None)
   >>> firstAdjective
   >>>
   ```

This example arose from answers to my question [Python: Expanding the scope of the iterator variable in the any() function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38476877/3001761)

Comment: Why *would* example 4 work? None of the strings in adjectives are a single character long, so no single character could possibly be `in` it. Example 2 iterates over `adjectives`, and e.g. `'or' in 'hello world'` works just fine.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I guess he does not know that iterating over a string iterates it `char` wise instead of word wise.

Comment: I would suggest you break this down into smaller steps, and use conventional `for` loops so you can `print` each step, rather than doing it in a *"black box"* and being surprised by the end result. For example, it's not clear to me why you thought you'd get a different result for example 2; you're asking for the first match from `adjectives`, not the first appearance in the `text` of *anything* from `adjectives`.

Answer (score 2):

Iterating on a string (`text`) will iterate on its characters, hence 4th loop could be rewritten more explicitly:

```
firstAdjective = next((character for character in text if character in adjectives), None)
```

Answer (score 0):

A string is a container, so `in` will still work on it.  However, it does not naturally separate into words, it iterates over characters.  In Example 4, `word` will take the value of each character in succession.  Giving it the variable name `word` doesn't make it a word.

In Example 2, you are iterating over the list `adjectives` rather than the string, so you get the "expected" behavior of `word` taking the value of a word.  Then the `in` operator checks whether `word` is a substring of `text` without having to use `split`.  Note that `text` is not split into words.  `'wn fo' in text` will return `True`.

Comment: `in` is not specific to iterators, but [containers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Container).